# Polygonize.py outputs into a single file or simple merge?

Tags: gdal, cartography, ogr, topography

Given an unique raster topographic file at start, I want to get **vector polygons for elevations thresholds** 1m, 200m, 500m, 1000m, 2000m into a single shp file. I first slice my raster into 5 (or more) rasters, then polygonize each, and then have to merge them.

**How to get these outputs into a single shape file ?** Either by sending them as layers directly into the same file, or by creating individual shp files to merge into one final shp.

---

**Current workflow details:** It seems I **must** do this because poligonize works on pixels with a same value (elevation) x.

**1. Generate raster slices:**
I used [gdal_calc.py](http://smathermather.wordpress.com/2011/12/01/gdal_calc-py-raster-calculator-using-numby-functions/) to generate kinds of vertical slices, with one .tif for each level :

```
gdal_calc.py -A crop.tif --outfile=level001.tif --calc="1*(A>0)"     --NoDataValue=0
gdal_calc.py -A crop.tif --outfile=level200.tif --calc="200*(A>200)" --NoDataValue=0
...
...
...
...
```

All conserved pixels in `level001.tif` have an elevation of 1.  All conserved pixels in `level200.tif` have an elevation of 200m. Opened together in QGis it give slices like this:

[image]

**2. Polygonize my rasters slices (files):**

I run [polygonize.py](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_polygonize.html) separatedly on each of these several raster files to get my vector layers:

```
gdal_polygonize.py level001.tif -f "ESRI Shapefile" levels001.shp levels001 elev
gdal_polygonize.py level200.tif -f "ESRI Shapefile" levels200.shp levels200 elev
...
...
...
...
```

**3. Merge** into one shp file.

> **How to merge these shp outputs ?**

Alternatively, I'am also interested by smoother workflow (loop).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the shapefiles to be merged are in the same directory:

```
ogr2ogr merge.shp levels001.shp
ogr2ogr -update -append merge.shp levels200.shp -nln merge
ogr2ogr -update -append merge.shp levels500.shp -nln merge
ogr2ogr -update -append merge.shp levels1000.shp -nln merge
ogr2ogr -update -append merge.shp levels2000.shp -nln merge
```